# Adding Prefix from cell value on row

Tags: excel, vba, loops, prefix

I'm creating a macro loop that takes the value from column A and adds it as a prefix to the rest of the cells after column D on that row. When it reaches an empty cell, it then goes to the next row and repeats the process until column A cell is empty. I have used this code which works on the first row, but I can't seem to get it to loop to the other rows.

```
Sub FLOC

Dim I as Integer 
Dim j as Integer
I=4
j=1
 'Check that Column A is not empty to stop the Loop
 While Not IsEmpty(Cells(j, 1))

  If Not IsEmpty(Cells(j,i)) Then
  'Select Column D in that row
  Cells(j, i).Select
 'Add the prefix from Column A to the rest of the Cells on the row
 ActiveCell.Value = Cells(1, j).Value & ActiveCell.Value
 i = i + 1

  'When a empty cell is reached move the ActiveCell to next row, Column D.
  Else
  i = 4
  j = j + 1

   Endif

   Wend

   Sub End
```

Any help on the right path would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post working code please, even if it errors. This code is not valid VBA. You have an Else but no If, "Sub End" instead of "End Sub" ...

Comment: Sorry here is the code,

Comment: Do you mean if you have "a" in A1, "b" in D1 and "c" in E1 then D1 should end up as "ab" and E1 should end up as "ac"?

Comment: Yes that's right. I figured out where I was going wrong.

Comment: Have you solved the problem then?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help I solved this with

```
Sub FLO2 ()        
Dim i As Double
Dim j As Double
Dim FLOC As String
j = 1
i = 4
FLOC = Cells(j, 1)

While Not IsEmpty(FLOC)

  If Not IsEmpty(Cells(j, i)) Then
  Cells(j, i).Select
  ActiveCell.Value = Cells(j, 1).Value & ActiveCell.Value
  i = i + 1
  Else
  i = 4
  j = j + 1
  End If

Wend
Sub End
```